# post data from c# to influxdb

Tags: c#, curl, http-post, influxdb

I have next recomendations to post data to InfluxDB:

```
curl -i -XPOST 'http://localhost:8086/write?db=mydb' --data-binary 'cpu_load_short,host=server01,region=us-west value=0.64 1434055562000000000'
```

But I don't know how to do it in c#.

Here's my code so far:

```
var httpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://192.168.0.102:8086/write?db=learning");
            httpWebRequest.ContentType = "*/*";
            httpWebRequest.Method = "POST";
            httpWebRequest.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
            httpWebRequest.Accept = "*/*";
            httpWebRequest.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("user", "pass");

            using (var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(httpWebRequest.GetRequestStream()))
            {
                string json = "AI1";
                streamWriter.Write(json);
                streamWriter.Flush();
                streamWriter.Close();
            }
```

Answer (score 3):

I think this is not working for me.
Here is my solution which works perfectly

```
 WebClient client = new WebClient();           
 var reponse = client.UploadString("http://localhost:8086/write?db=mydb", "cpu_load_short,host=server01,region=us-west value=0.64 1434055562000000000");
```

Answer (score 2):

Here how i decide it

```
string data, Uri address
try
    {
         var client = new HttpClient();
         var d = new StreamContent(GenerateStreamFromString(data));
         var response = await client.PostAsync(address, d);
         response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
    }
catch
    {
         Console.WriteLine("Error in writing to DB");
    }

public static Stream GenerateStreamFromString(string s)
{
    MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream();
    StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(stream);
    writer.Write(s);
    writer.Flush();
    stream.Position = 0;
    return stream;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would do it like so using [System.Net.Http.HttpClient](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpclient?view=netframework-4.8), or even better, use [InfluxDB.NET](https://github.com/ziyasal/InfluxDB.Net)

```
    static async Task InfluxPostAsync()
    {
        var influxPostData = "influxdbname,tag1=tag1value value=1000";

        using (var client = new System.Net.Http.HttpClient())
        {
            client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://influxserver:8086");
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new System.Net.Http.Headers.AuthenticationHeaderValue("Basic", "aW5mblahblahblahblahblahNXMyNQ==");
            var content = new System.Net.Http.StringContent(influxPostData, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
            var result = await client.PostAsync("/write?db=influxdbname&precision=s", content);
            string resultContent = await result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        }
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Task.Run(() => InfluxPostAsync());
    }
```